# Can Naruto use Planetary Devastation?

Tags: naruto

Can Naruto use Planetary Devastation? If no, then why? He has the Sage of Six Path's powers too right? Then why can't he use Planetary Devastation?

Comment: Does he have a rinnegan?

Comment: no but he has the sage of six path's power..

Comment: I would say no. Because cannon said so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Planetary Devastation is a technique unique to the RINNEGAN which means it is an dojutsu.

Answer (score -1):

I say **maybe**, because he *kind of* used it with Sasuke against Kaguya. Note that both Naruto and Sasuke say Planetary Devastation and not Sakura, so it kinda leaves it in the air.

[image]

Comment: It’s not clear to me that both Naruto and Sasuke say “Chibaku Tensei” in the manga. In the anime, only Sasuke says the name of the jutsu.